# pthread to invoke member func by wrapping it externally

Tags: class, pthreads, wrapper, member

I'm trying to invoke a member function by pthread by using an external wrapper but it doesn't quite work for me, I get a seg fault. Why is this?
Here's a little test program that displays the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
class test {    
    public:
        test();
        ~test();
        void RunTh(void);
    private:
        pthread_t *pid;
};
void *Run_wrp(void *context);
void test::RunTh(void)
{
    while(1);
}
test::test()
{
    pthread_create(pid,NULL,&Run_wrp,this);
}
test::~test(){}

int main(void) {
    test tmp;
    std::cin.get();
}

void *Run_wrp(void *context)
{
    ((test*)context)->RunTh();
}
```

Comment: ’pid’ is just a pointer, but not an actual ’pthread_t’ object - try removing the ’*’, and then just dereferencing it with ’&’ in your call to ’pthread_create()’.

Comment: Also, if you make ’Run_wrp’ a static member function of your class, you can keep everything nicely inside it, instead of having to rely on external helpers.

Comment: @sonicwave If you move your first comment into an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pid` member variable is just a pointer, not an actual `pthread_t` object.

Change it to:

```
private:
    pthread_t pid;
```

Then create the new thread with:

```
pthread_create(&pid,NULL,&Run_wrp,this);
```

Also, if you want to keep everything contained in the class, you can make your `Run_wrp()` function a `static` member function of `test`, as long as you keep the same signature (return value/arguments). It needs to be `static`, as non-`static` functions take the `this` pointer to the class as a hidden argument, and thus end up with a different signature than what you need for `pthread_create()`.